# PhantomJS 1.9.7 on Win2008 Server doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery, windows, https, phantomjs

I've setup a very basic test page with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var a = 1;
            });
        </script>

</body></html>
```

However this fails to load the jQuery library under Windows 2008 Server and throws a javascript error on the 'var a = 1' assignment. If I change it to http protocol, it seems to be loading the page without errors on Windows 2008 Server. The same script however works just fine with https mode on Windows 7.

Actual phantom Script:

```
var system = require('system');

if (system.args.length < 3) {
    console.log("Missing arguments.");
    phantom.exit();
}

var server = require('webserver').create();
var port = parseInt(system.args[1]);
var urlPrefix = system.args[2];

var parse_qs = function(s) {
    var queryString = {};
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = s;
    a.search.replace(
        new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"),
        function($0, $1, $2, $3) { queryString[$1] = $3; }
    );
    return queryString;
};

var renderHtml = function(url, cb) {
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.settings.loadImages = false;
    page.settings.localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled = false;
    page.onCallback = function() {
        cb(page.content);
        page.close();
    };
    page.onInitialized = function() {
       page.evaluate(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.callPhantom();
            }, 10000);
        });
    };

    page.open(url, function(status) {
       console.log('Status: ' + status);
    });

    page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
        console.log(new Date());
      console.log(msg);
      trace.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
      });
    }

};

server.listen(port, function (request, response) {
    var url = 'https://www.sometestsite.com/test.html';
    renderHtml(url, function(html) {
        //console.log(html);
        response.statusCode = 200;
        response.write(html);
        response.close();
    });
});

console.log('Listening on ' + port + '...');
console.log('Press Ctrl+C to stop.');
```

Below is the error I get on Win 2008 Server, tried passing --web-security=false as well:

C:\PhantomJS>phantomjs --disk-cache=no --web-security=false myscript.j
s 7778 https://www.sometestsite.com/
Listening on 7778...
Press Ctrl+C to stop.
Status: success
Wed Aug 13 2014 08:03:59 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
https://www.sometestsite.com/test.html : 8

Any ideas why the code above works on Windows 7 but not on Windows 2008 Server?

Thanks